# Prove every linearly independent set is contained in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that linear space L has a basis with a finite number of points, B = {P1,
>   P2, P3, ... Pn} Then every linearly independent set is contained in a
>   basis.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this. I know that no linearly independent set can be larger than basis B, but I'm not sure how to prove there isn't a linearly independent set outside of the basis.

Comment: Is $L$ a vectorspace here? $L=\mathbb R^2$ has $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ as basis. $\{(1,1)\}$ is a linearly independent subset. However, it is not contained in the basis that is mentioned.

Comment: L is just a generic linear space.

Comment: @drhab But {(1,1)} is still contained in a basis, as the claim claims.

Comment: What does "there isn't one outside of the basis" mean - what "one" are you referring to? Are you trying to prove there isn't a different basis which is bigger than B? (Which isn't the content of the greyboxed claim.)

Comment: Sorry, I mean there isn't a linearly independent set not contained in the basis.

Comment: @seaturtles I red 'the basis' instead of 'a basis'. I red wrongly or things have been changed by an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You show this by simply *adding* vectors to some linearly independent set $X$ until you find a basis. You start with some linearly independent set $X = X_0$, and $k = 0$.

1. Let $S_k = \textrm{span }X_k$.
2. If $S_k = L$, we're done. By construction $X_k$ is linearly independent, and it spans $L$, so by definition it's a basis.
3. Otherwise, pick an arbitrary $x_k \in L \setminus S_k$. Since $x_k \notin S_k$, $x_k$ is linearly independent from $X_k$.
4. Set $X_{k+1} = X_k \cup \{x_k\}$, which by (3) is a linearly independent set
5. Continue at (1), with $k := k + 1$

Since $L$ is finite-dimensional, this algorithm must stop at some point, because if $L$ has dimension $n$, no set with more than $n$ elements can be linearly independent. But if the algorithm stops during iteration $k$, then $X_k$ is a basis, and by construction $X_k \supset X$.

Therefore, whenever we're given a linearly independent set $X$, we can run this algorithm to find a basis $X_k$ which includes $X$.

Comment: To do this proof rigorously you need to prove that in a $n$-dimensional vector space no set of $n+1$ vectors can be linearly independent.

Comment: How does that prove that all linearly independent sets are in the basis though?

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh I stated that requirement. My guess was that the OP has seen a proof for this in class or in a text-book. But true, if one *doesn't* already know this, it'll have to be proven at some point...

Comment: @lindsey What do you mean? By construction, all the (larger and larger) linearly independent sets this algorithm constructs extend the original set - we only *add* vectors. And we only *add* vectors that don't intefere with linear independence, so the resulting sets are all linearly independent. What is ".. are in the basis ... " supposed to mean?

Comment: @lindsey Hm, I named the linearly independent set $B$, whereas you used that name for some pre-defined basis. Maybe that was the source of confusion - renamed to $X$ instead.

Comment: Sorry this kind of stuff really isn't a strong point for me. I'm supposed to be proving that every linearly independent set is contained in a basis. I started by assuming that there was a linearly independent set not in a basis in an attempt to find a contradiction, but that wouldn't be the way to go?

Comment: @lindsey There are many different ways to prove this. The prove I showed you isn't by contradiction, but rather explicitly constructs a basis by starting from a linearly independent set $X$ and adding vectors...

Answer (score 1):

For this proof you need to show that:

1. Any linearly independent set with less than $n$ vectors can be extended to be a basis. fgp shows how to do that another answer
2. There can bo no linearly independent set with more vectors than a basis.

I am not going to repeat part 1 - fgp did a good job of that (+1 from my side ;)). For part 2 you need to pick any $n+1$ vectors and show that they are linearly dependent. This means you must show in the standard way: if \begin{equation} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i\beta_i=0 \end{equation} then there exist $a_i$ so that not all the $a_i$ are zero. It is quite straightforward (but a little cumbersome) in this case,: you do it by just expressing each of the $\beta_i$ in terms of the basis $B$ (so $\beta_i=\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ji}B_j$), and then substitute each sum into the equation above, and after some rearrangement you will end up with: \begin{equation} \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} b_{1j}a_j B_1+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} b_{2j}a_j B_2 + \cdots + \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} b_{nj}a_j B_n = 0. \end{equation} Now each of the coefficients is a sum which must be zero (by the linear independence of the basis), so taking each of these "coefficient equations" together we then have a homogenous system with more unknowns than equations, meaning it will always have a nontrivial solution.